# Default program for scanner in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scanner, file-association

I have a cannon canoscan scanner and windows 7 pro.

When I press the scan button on the scanner I get a choose program dialog. My 2 choices are Photoshop and Picasa. I want to add other programs, like Irfanview and plain old windows paint, how can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

This is NOT the autoplay handler, it is the event handler. Go to `Control Panel\Hardware` and `Sound\Devices` and `Printers`.

Pick your scanner and right click `Scan Properties`, click on the `Events` tab and you should be able to change the setting.

For epson scanners go [here](http://files.support.epson.com/htmldocs/prv6ph/prv6phug/projs_11.htm)

Comment: My only option is take no action.

Comment: I spent hours searching and thought that would help.  Maybe you could try to uninstall the scanner software, unplug the device and then reinstall the software and plug in USB device.  If you still don't see option such as start this program or prompt for action then reinstall winows?? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Reinstalling windows seems to be more trouble than worth, plus it is not my call to do this. I have the same problem as @RonnieOverby, as the options to choose a program are grayed out. The drivers for the printer/scanner were installed automatically on plugging in the printer. How to reinstall them?

Comment: You can add your own event handlers by adding 2 registry keys. The method is [described here](http://icopy.sourceforge.net/register-your-application-to-scanner-events/)

Answer (score 1):

These are called autoplay handlers. You can configure them with [TweakUI](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/tweakui.htm) under **My Computer -> Autoplay -> Handlers**.

Comment: TweakUI does not work on Windows 7, does it?

Comment: @snark http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista

Comment: OK, thanks. This is not the "official" MS TweakUI.

Comment: John's first link is for XP

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get a fast, simple scanning utility is to go to system32/wiaacmgr.exe and "send" a shortcut to your desktop.  Then, just click on it and the scan utility pops up!

Answer (score 0):

Note:  Update/Addition to above correct answer:

Current path is Control Panel\Devices and Printers, and then right click on your scanner and select SCAN PROPERTIES (not Properties).  Select the Events tab and select radio button "Start this program" and select your scanner from the dropdown list.

NOTE:  be sure to do this for all evens in the "Select an event" dropdown.  My CanoScan LiDE device had 4 events, corresponding to the buttons on the front (Copy, Scan, Email, PDF).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The printers/devices seem to be the way for win 7, though I had to change all the buttons to get it to automatically open the file. But that is where the list of devices reside.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This answer doesn't seem very actionable, it isn't clear exactly what to do to solve the problem in the question.  Can you edit the answer to elaborate?  Thanks.